# Remove header title form page through CSS

Tags: customization, css

I would like to change the size of the message on my shopping-cart page, for example:

http://leerenveerkracht.nl/2016wp/?page_id=4912

If a product is added, there a large message appears (*Winkelwagen*). I messed around with inspect element and got rid of the extra space, but I'm not versed in coding enough to get the right code in the `style.css` file of my child theme.

Is there any way I can simply get rid of the following for that page?

```
<div class='c12 end pageheading'>
```

When I play around with it in the inspect element the problem disappears. Does anybody have suggestions?

Comment: Thanks @ethan-jinks-osullivan for the edits in terminology in my question. The other problem with Woocommerce was fixed when I deleted and re-uploaded the functions.php in my child-theme folder (no clue why this worked, but it did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the title (*Winkelwagen*) from that page:

[image]

This is the CSS that you want to run:

```
.c12.end.pageheading {
    display: none;
}
```

You can add that to your child theme's `style.css`, or you can add the following to your child theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'hide_winkelwagen' );

function hide_winkelwagen() {
    ?>
    <style itype='text/css'>
        .c12.end.pageheading {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Either one will give you the same result.